# Android licensing server real use scenario?

Tags: android

It seems like the example they give for the licensing server uses the main activities window to display licensing.  I'm wondering what is a realworld example that uses the licensing server.

Use their main sample activity and if it allows go right to your actual main activity?

It seems like there should be a sample that checks access with NO UI but pops up a UI only in the case of a licensing problem.  That sounds more realworld to me.

Is there some example code that shows an example like that somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> "Use their main sample activity and if
>   it allows go right to your actual main
>   activity?"

If I understand you right, the answer is "absolutely not". And the code there IS the example that 99% of the world uses. I use it. I just add a couple of mHandler.post and that's generally all I need. Tie with dialogs...

The licensing stuff does not use any activity. That activity is the real world example. It's just used to demonstrate the possible outcomes of the code.

You don't reuse the example activity. The license checker stuff happens in the background, and it's not tied to any UI elements (AFAIK). You are the only one responsible for posting UI elements back from the license checker inner class (that implements LicenseCheckerCallback) in the way you feel appropriate for your code logic.

Mind you, you don't even need to post any UI stuff back from the class to your activity. Depending on what you're trying to do, you may do all your logic without exposing anything to the user.

It seems to me you're not understanding the concept correctly.